# Make arrow point downward when accordion is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using Zebra Accordion. Not the best one out there but it's 100% compatible with jQuery 1.5.2, which is outdated, obviously.

Anyway, I want the arrow to point downward when the user click on the accordion, very much like this:

**http://jqueryui.com/accordion/**

This is currently my page right now, if you go to Alchemy in Detail tab you'll find the two Accordions there:

**http://www.planet.nu/dev/test-2/product-page.html**

This is the CSS for the Zebra Accordion:

```
dl.Zebra_Accordion { width: 740px; font-size: 14px; }
dl.Zebra_Accordion dt { background: #878787; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; padding: 8px; }
dl.Zebra_Accordion dt:hover { background: #0095da; }
dl.Zebra_Accordion dd { background: #EFEFEF; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 305px; margin: 0; }
dl.Zebra_Accordion dt.Zebra_Accordion_Expanded { background: #0095da; }
```

This is the HTML:

```
<dl class="Zebra_Accordion">
            <dt><p class="accordion-header">Managed Services</p></dt>
            <dd>
               <p><span>Alchemy Social’s Managed Service solution works with businesses of all sizes — from brand new start-ups to established multinationals — ensuring that they connect with and engage the right social audiences.</span></p>
                <p>Our teams combine the perfect blend of skills, from traditional digital display through search to creative design. With offices around the world, we manage campaigns and support our clients whenever and wherever they need us:</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="alchemy-product-list">Full campaign management, from goal setting/strategy through to delivery and reporting</li>
                        <li class="alchemy-product-list">Targeting and segmentation planning</li>
                        <li class="alchemy-product-list">Custom built creative generation on demand (image and copy)</li>
                        <li class="alchemy-product-list">Daily optimisation</li>
                        <li class="alchemy-product-list">Regular reporting</li>
                        <li class="alchemy-product-list">Campaign review</li>
                        <li class="alchemy-product-list">Access to Experian’s unique and proprietary data assets to improve campaigns</li>
                    </ul>
            </dd>
            <dt>Licensed Services<img src="img/arrow-white.png" class="white-arrow"></dt>
            <dd>
                <p><span>As the social space evolves at tremendous speed, even the most experienced in-house teams can need support to stay ahead of the curve.</span></p>
                <p>Experian’s Alchemy Social Licensed solutions offer flexible, on-demand services to meet every need. Our client services team is amongst the most experienced in the industry, offering scalable support to your social strategies and campaigns.</p>
                <p><span>Alchemy SaaS</span></p>
                <p>Licensing the Alchemy Social Platform brings access to the full range of features of the Facebook ads manager platform, including:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Guidance on how to create, manage, report on and optimise campaigns</li>
                    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Access to regular webinars on new releases, features and best practices</li>
                    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Dedicated account management support and consultative advice</li>
                    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Create campaign rules for real-time cost per acquisition (CPA) optimisation</li>
                    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Effectively refine activity at various points of the campaign cycle</li>
                    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Control ad spend at segment level by location or target group</li>
                    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Analyse conversion data and integrate with other analytical tools</li>
                    <li class="alchemy-product-list">View real-time reporting to understand CPA and conversion rates at ad level</li>
                    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Integrate campaign results with tools like Google Analytics and Adobe Omniture</li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
```

I'll also include a bit of the main CSS code as well, this is from alchemy-product-style.css:

```
.accordion-header:after{
    content: url(../img/arrow-white.png);
    padding-left: 10px;
}

dl.Zebra_Accordion dt .accordion-header{
    color: #FFF !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you add a rule like:

```
.Zebra_Accordion_Expanded .white-arrow {
  transform: rotate(90deg); // You should prefix this accordingly to your needs.
}
```

Support for CSS3 transforms [is pretty good at the moment](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), but if you need support older browsers, I would do it just like in jQueryUI accordions. They have a `<span>` for the arrow-icon, and when then the background of the icon is changed according to it's state.

It would look something like this:

HTML:

```
<dt class="Zebra_Accordion_Expanded">
  Licensed Services
  <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
</dt>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url(../img/arrow-white.png) center no-repeat;
}

.Zebra_Accordion_Expanded .arrow icon {
  background-image: url(../img/arrow-white-down.png);
}
```

This should work, but it's just an example. Keep in mind that using 2 images would create an extra http request, and using [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) would be a more elegant solution in this case.

Hope it helped you.

— **FF**

Answer (score 0):

Ok - here's a fiddle to demonstrate my approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/afpgpngo/

Change your css to respond to the Zebra_AccordionExpanded style that gets set by Zebra ...

```
dl.Zebra_Accordion dt.Zebra_Accordion_Expanded .accordion-header:after{
    content: "put link to downward facing arrow";
    padding-left: 10px;
}

dl.Zebra_Accordion dt .accordion-header:after{
    content: url(http://www.planet.nu/dev/test-2/img/arrow-white.png);
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

And also make sure you change your html to be consistent:

```
<dt><p class="accordion-header">Managed Services</p></dt>
```

and

```
<dt><p class="accordion-header">Licensed Services</p></dt>
```

(the css inserts after the accordion-header class)

Comment: This is the way I would personally do it too, Birgit. But I thought that it would deviate too much from what Richard already got implemented. Nice one, anyway. :)